# UISegmentedControl: how not to highlight already selected segment when using custom images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using custom images for normal/selected states of `UISegmentedControl`.
When I tap already selected segment, it's appearance changes to highlighted.

I've tried to set image for highlighted+selected state, but it's ignored:

```
   [segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:appearance.selectedBackground
                                forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Is there any way (including non-breaking private ones) to have the selected segment in selected state when it's tapped again?

Comment: check for this link if it is useful ....https://github.com/u10int/URBSegmentedControl

Comment: @Adi I've seen a lot of implementations, but currently I am interested in customised standard one

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late but for those who have the same issue:
You have to set all the dividerImages for each states

```
// Set background images
UIImage *normalBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-background-unselected"];
UIImage *selectedBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-background-selected"];
[self setBackgroundImage:normalBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:normalBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Set divider images
UIImage *buttonImageLeftSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-left-selected"];
UIImage *buttonImageNoneSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-none-selected"];
UIImage *buttonImageRightSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-right-selected"];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageNoneSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple and worked perfect for me, but you need to subclass and override the `touchesBegan` method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIControl *control in self.subviews) {
        if ([control respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && control.isSelected) {
            // found our selected segment, now check if we actually tapped it
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(control.frame, [touch locationInView:self])) {
                // tapping selected segment, do nothing. this avoids highligting it
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```